# Moving rectangular box showing in Ubuntu desktop

Tags: 20.04, desktop-environments, .desktop

Rectangular box flickering in my Ubuntu desktop. When i scroll mouse pointer above it it fades and come again in the desktop. Issue persist after reboot also.

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Please see the image below :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Solved the issue by installing ubuntu desktop package.**

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```